# Fetch the records from DB for Hourly report

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I want to fetch the sales records from db based on the time. For **each hour** i have to calculate the total sale. how to do this in **Sqlite**?

```
My_DB
{
sale_date,
sale_time,
tot_amt,
net_amt
}
```

i want to display the details in report like:

```
01:00-02:00     totamt
02:00-03:00     totamt
```

Comment: What is the format of the values in the `sale_time` column?

Comment: 00:07:28.372 this is the format. But displaying in reports i need HH:MM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hour is in the first two characters of the timestamps, so you want to group by that:

```
SELECT substr(sale_time, 1, 2) AS hour,
       sum(tot_amt) as totamt
FROM My_DB
GROUP BY hour
```

The database cannot return results for data that does not exist, so if you want result for all hours, you have to have a list of them first:

```
SELECT hour,
       (SELECT sum(tot_amt)
        FROM My_DB
        WHERE substr(sale_time, 1, 2) = hour)
FROM (SELECT '00' AS hour UNION ALL
      SELECT '01'         UNION ALL
      SELECT '02'         UNION ALL
      ...
      SELECT '22'         UNION ALL
      SELECT '23')
```

If you want to get zero instead of NULL for missing entries, use `total()` instead of `sum()`.

Comment: i want to display the details for every hour (1-24). how to do that?

Comment: One more doubt..If i want to display the details for specific time range like (0-7,7-12,12-16,16-24), then how we can proceed?

Comment: That would be a different question. But you'd need two columns in the list for min/max.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(tot_amt)
FROM My_DB
WHERE sale_time >= TIME('01:00:00.000') 
AND sale_time <= TIME('02:00:00.000')
```

Use your IDE to build these statements on demand and substitute the value in the TIME() function with your wanted values. In case you also need the date just use `AND sale_date = DATE('2014-08-11')` in addition.

Comment: This query is fine. But i want to display the details for complete day.1-2,2-3....23-24hour.